# How to set up elasticsearch and filebeat

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I have installed elasicsearch and filebeat.

The filebeat config:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["https://myElastic:9200"]
  username: "user"
  password: "password"
```

Could you please tell me, do I need to configure something in elasticsearch.
The problem that I have now is that I do not see data from filebeat in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your filebeat config should have input lines.

filebeat.yml :

```yml
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    - /mylog/*.log

output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: ["https://myElastic:9200"]
  username: "user"
  password: "password"
```

and I recommend you use logstash with filebeat.
You can find how to config it easily in below github repository.

> docker-compose config : [ELK with Filebeat by Docker-compose](https://github.com/gnokoheat/elk-with-filebeat-by-docker-compose)